# Crop an image using multiple points and flexible size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, crop

I want to make an application like a cam scanner for cropping a document.

I am using `VNDetectDocumentSegmentationRequest` for scanning a document I getting rest from it.
but I am not figuring out how they are working with `UIBazierPath` or `CALayer`.
I am stuck on this for a few days.
here are some images of how I want it.
[image]

Comment: I think they have dedicated library for detecting the object and processing the text or the content in that. I think if you want something like that you supposed to create it or you supposed to pay it(I'm not sure what all the api's availble). for the labels recognization you can use google MLKit(really good to use I have experienced)

Comment: ok I'll try that @Jok3r

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure if this answers your question, but here is a function that takes in the original image and the `VNRectangleObservation` (which you get from the `VNDetectDocumentSegmentationRequest`) and returns a cropped image.

```swift
private func croppedAndCorrectedImage(from inputImage: CIImage, rectangleObservation: VNRectangleObservation) -> CIImage? {
    let imageSize = inputImage.extent.size

    // Ensure that the detected rectangle is valid.
    let boundingBox = rectangleObservation.boundingBox.scaled(to: imageSize)
    guard inputImage.extent.contains(boundingBox) else {
        print("Invalid Detected Rectangle")
        return nil
    }
    // Rectify the detected image
    let topLeft = rectangleObservation.topLeft.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let topRight = rectangleObservation.topRight.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let bottomLeft = rectangleObservation.bottomLeft.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let bottomRight = rectangleObservation.bottomRight.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let correctedImage = inputImage
        .cropped(to: boundingBox)
        .applyingFilter("CIPerspectiveCorrection", parameters: [
            "inputTopLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: topLeft),
            "inputTopRight": CIVector(cgPoint: topRight),
            "inputBottomLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomLeft),
            "inputBottomRight": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomRight)
        ])

    return correctedImage
}
```

To let users **edit** the crop, I'd recommend tweaking the above function to also return the rectangle's points (`top-left`, `top-right`, `bottom-left`, `bottom-right`).

From there you can build a view for displaying the crop, and allowing the user to edit it. (take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/artemkrachulov/AKImageCropperView) for inspiration).

Comment: brother I have done that for the auto feature but for the manual feature, I need that cropper. but thankyou.